# How to import AXIOS into NestJS-application the right way?

Tags: node.js, axios, nestjs

Importing `HttpService` from **AXIOS** into **NestJS**-Application seems to be a little mess at the moment.

When importing HttpModule like suggest on so many other SO-pages like

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
```

it will state an error message

```
Potential solutions:
- If HttpService is a provider, is it part of the current WalletsModule?
- If HttpService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within WalletsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing HttpService */ ]
  })
```

Instead, one should use the following import:

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
```

Even the `import` of HttpModule needs to be imported from the `common`-namespace. Otherwise it will still give the same error message.

However, this one is already marked as deprecated and says that one should import from `@nestjs/axios` instead, which leads to the already mentioned import error above.

What is happening here and why and which one should be actually used now?

package.json:

```
"@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.7",
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/schedule": "^1.0.2",
"@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.5",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
```

Comment: Did you add `HttpModule` as imports  (the one from `@nestjs/axios`) in your `WalletsModule` ?

Comment: looks like you've imported the _nodejs_ package but not the nestjs module. You should do both, of course

Comment: @DamDam yes, the axios-namespace causes the errors at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `HttpModule` inside of `FooModule` like so,

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios'

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule], // HttpModule.register() works too
  providers: [FooService],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

And now you can make use of `HttpService` inside of `FooService`,

```js
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
}
```

The `HttpModule` and `HttpService` from `@nestjs/common` are deprecated, and will be removed in the next major version of `@nestjs/common`.